# How to change a direction of growth for boxes?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, boxes

I have read [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Articles/Pandora%E2%80%99s_%5Chbox%3A_Using_LuaTeX_to_Lift_the_Lid_of_TeX_Boxes#Boxes_and_glue:_A_brief_reminder) that it is possible to change the direction of growth in horizontal boxes.

> Note: horizontal boxes can, of course, contain text typeset in right-to-left languages, such as Arabic or Hebrew, which means the direction of box growth can be opposite to that shown for the horizontal box in the diagram below.

Could anyone point me to how this can be achieved? Does this happen automatically when using right-to-left languages? Is it possible to change the direction of growth in vertical boxes too?

Comment: Sorry to say that, your question is not clear, can you show any reference image for your boxes?

Comment: Do you mean you want to right-align a horizontal box to some point, or do you mean you want the text direction to be right to left?

Comment: Sorry, I am still a bit new to boxes and modes... I was trying to ask my question abstractly as I am curious if you can be adding letters/boxes right to left or bottom to top in vertical mode.

Comment: the details depend on the engine xetex and pdftex are similar, luatex is quite different, ptex has specific modes for Japanese vertical text see for example [tag:bidi]